# Okhttp convert Response to Spring ResponseEntity

Tags: java, spring-boot, httpresponse, okhttp

I have a Springboot 2.2 webservice with a POST REST api.
I am using Okhttp client to make the request to a third party service.
I want to return the exact response from the third party service to the caller of my webservice.
All the okhttp recipes refer to:

```
 if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

      System.out.println(response.body().string());
```

I have tried returning the okhttp Response in my api but I only return to the caller example:

```
{
    "redirect": false,
    "successful": true
}
```

So it does not insert the message returned from the third party service.

Does anyone know how to convert Okhttp Response object to a Spring ResponseEntity object so that I may return the **http response code and message**

Comment: can you add your okhttp related code to the op ie. how you create and send/receive the request.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you can use the `HttpServletResponse` in the Spring-Webservice directly and pipe the InputStream given from okhttp ResponseBody to the OutputStream of the `HttpServletResponse`.

```
@PostMapping(path="/my/webservice")
public void postSomething(HttpServletResponse response)throws IOException{
   okhttp3.Response redirectedResponse = redirectCall();
   if(redirectedResponse.isSuccessful())
     pipe(response.getOutputStream(), redirectedResponse.body.byteStream());
}

private void pipe(OutputStream output, InputStream input)throws IOException{
   byte chunk[] = new byte[1024];
   while(input.read(chunk, 0, 1024) != -1){
     output.write(chunk);
   }
}
```

Comment: can you explain how `pipe` is working here and from where it is?

Comment: I added a sample method. `pipe` pipes a small amount (1024 bytes) of the third party response (input stream) to the output stream of the current request until the end of this input stream is reached.

Comment: Is `pipe` a build-in function, if not, how can I create one custom `pipe` function?

Comment: No it's not a build function. You should add this function to the Spring-Controller.

Comment: Any example, or any reference link, sorry I am a bit new to spring boot.

Comment: I tried the same code, and I was expecting an image, got only a part of it, but its ok, I found soem other solution, I created a new ResponseEntity and filled body with the `redirectedResponse `'s body as bytes and it worked.